# Create pre-defined aggregate view in SurrealD

Tags: surrealdb

I have a **user** table like below:

[image]

I also have a **city** table like below:

[image]

I then use the RELATE statement to create graph edges between user and city in a new table called **post** which looks like below:

[image]

I now want to create a new pre-defined aggregate view called **post_stats** which derives it's data from **post** and should look like below. Can someone help me with the exact statements to achieve this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```sql
define table post_stats as
select 
    out as city_id, 
    count(action = "favorites") as favorites_count,
    count(action = "check_in") as check_in,
    count(action = "bucket_list") as bucket_list
from post
group by out;
```